# Binding to element position does not work?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have an image with opacity mask and wish to add possibility to resize/reposition that opacity mask.
I'm a complete WPF newbie, so may be may thinking is completely wrong, feel free to throw any ideas at me :)

So I have this:

```xml
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas">
    <Rectangle Width="197.016" Height="120.896" Canvas.Left="76.119" Canvas.Top="73.134" Name="SelectionRectangle"></Rectangle>
    <Image Source="Chrysanthemum.jpg" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainCanvas, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MainCanvas, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <RadialGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" 
                                 Center="{Binding ElementName=SelectionRectangle, Converter={StaticResource RectangleConverter}}" 
                                 GradientOrigin="{Binding ElementName=SelectionRectangle, Converter={StaticResource RectangleConverter}}" 
                                 RadiusY="{Binding ElementName=SelectionRectangle, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}" 
                                 RadiusX="{Binding ElementName=SelectionRectangle, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}">
                <GradientStop Color="#7C15161F" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF40499E" Offset="0.999" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF182395" Offset="0" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

So there's image with RadialGradientBrush mask and I'm trying to bind RadialGradientBrush center to rectangles center using this converter:

```
public class RectangleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var rectangle = (Rectangle)value;
        return new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(rectangle) + rectangle.ActualWidth / 2f, Canvas.GetTop(rectangle) + rectangle.ActualHeight / 2f);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and runs, but works incorrectly, I guess because when Rectangle position changes, RadialGradientBrush Center binding does not know about that (at least breaking point in converter is not hit by changing rectangle's position).
What would be the easiest/recommended way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found, that Multibinding can solve this problem:

```xml
  <Canvas Name="MainCanvas">
    <Rectangle Width="197.016" Height="120.896" Canvas.Left="76.119" Canvas.Top="73.134" Name="SelectionRectangle"></Rectangle>
    <Image Source="Chrysanthemum.jpg" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainCanvas, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=MainCanvas, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Image.OpacityMask>
            <RadialGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute"                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                 RadiusY="{Binding ElementName=SelectionRectangle, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}" 
                                 RadiusX="{Binding ElementName=SelectionRectangle, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE/2}">                    
                <RadialGradientBrush.Center>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectangleConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="(Canvas.Left)"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="ActualWidth"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="(Canvas.Top)"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RadialGradientBrush.Center>
                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectangleConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="(Canvas.Left)"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="ActualWidth"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="(Canvas.Top)"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="SelectionRectangle" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RadialGradientBrush.GradientOrigin>
                <GradientStop Color="#7C15161F" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF40499E" Offset="0.999" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF182395" Offset="0" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Image.OpacityMask>

    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

And converter:

```
 public class RectangleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Point((double)values[0] + (double)values[1] / 2d, (double)values[2] + (double)values[3] / 2d);            
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Not sure if I'm right, but my explanation would be - in question I was binding to whole object, so it is not a dependency property, so mask was not notified about the changes.
Now multibinding let's to specify which exactly properties are interesting and value converter get's notification when any of them change.